# Пытаюсь создать предмет обучения, содержащий список преподавателей

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

У меня есть предмет обучения, который читают несколько преподавателей.
Subject содержит поля int subjectID, String subjectName и List teachersList.
При создании нового предмета subjectName добавляется корректно, а с добавлением списка учителей путем выбора из уже существующего списка проблема.

Контроллер:

```
@GetMapping("/addsubjects")
public String newSubject(@ModelAttribute("subject") Subject subject, @ModelAttribute("teachers") Teacher teacher, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("teachers", teacherSI.getTeachersList());
    return "subjects/addsubjects";
}

@PostMapping()
public String addSubject(@RequestParam("subjectName") String subjectName, @RequestParam("teachersList") List<Teacher> teachersList) {
    Subject subject = new Subject.SubjectBuilder().buildSubjectName(subjectName).buildTeachersList(teachersList)
            .build();
    subjectSI.addSubject(subject);
    return "redirect:/subjects";
}
```

Вьюшка:

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/subjects}" th:object="${subject}">
    <div>
        <label for="subjectName">Enter subject name:</label> 
        <input type="text" th:field="*{subjectName}" id="subjectName">
        <br> 
        <label for="subjectTeacher">Select teachers:</label> 
        <select multiple="multiple" th:object="${teacher}" th:field="*{teachersList}" id="subjectTeacher">
            <option th:each="teacher : ${teachers}"
                th:field="*{teachersList}"
                th:value="${teacher}"
                th:text="${teacher.getSecondName()}">teacher</option>
        </select>
        <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </div>
</form>
```

На сервере появляется ошибка "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'teacher' available as request attribute"

Comment: Здравствуйте. Что значит "Что я делаю не так?"? Какая-то ошибка появляется? Что-то не работает? Поправьте ваш вопрос, указав в нём проблему с помощью кнопки внизу вопроса "Править"

Comment: Исправил. Сервер выдаёт ошибку "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'teacher' available as request attribute"